# Long (2 Pages) and Wide Table: Use longtable and adjustbox package in Latex

Tags: longtable, textwidth

I have to create a long and wide table for my note. I plan to divide the table into two pages: so I use longtable package. And because it is wide, I tried to keep it as text width and for this I use adjustbox package. The code as per below. However it didnt work as I expect because somehow the caption appears in the middle of the table. Kindly need your help.

```
\begin{longtable}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Town}} & \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} & \textbf{Col3} & \textbf{Col4} & \textbf{Col5} & \textbf{Col6} & \textbf{Col7} & \textbf{Col8} & \textbf{Col9} & \textbf{Col10} & \textbf{Col11} \\
    \midrule
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{AAA} & 8.88  & 12.34 & 13.74 & 15.17 & 16.45 & 18.03 & 18.49 & 19.09 & 19.02 & 19.21 & 10.34 \\
          & (3.29) & (2.98) & (2.9) & (2.84) & (2.87) & (2.89) & (2.98) & (3.05) & (2.99) & (3.33) & (2.73) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{BBB} & 20.84 & 18.73 & 17.47 & 15.45 & 16.33 & 15.55 & 15.17 & 14.50 & 14.00 & 12.25 & -8.59 \\
          & (3.82) & (3.5) & (3.27) & (3.13) & (3)   & (2.89) & (2.81) & (2.81) & (2.68) & (2.42) & (3.06) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{CCC} & 14.64 & 14.40 & 15.83 & 16.36 & 17.31 & 17.13 & 16.88 & 16.57 & 15.44 & 15.86 & 1.23 \\
          & (2.71) & (2.96) & (2.92) & (2.89) & (2.92) & (2.99) & (2.9) & (2.99) & (3.14) & (3.11) & (1.77) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{DDD} & 8.60  & 12.13 & 13.07 & 14.58 & 15.95 & 16.57 & 17.34 & 18.66 & 20.21 & 23.41 & 14.82 \\
          & (3.31) & (3.08) & (2.91) & (2.86) & (2.81) & (2.79) & (2.84) & (2.84) & (2.99) & (3.42) & (2.28) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{EEE} & 16.36 & 17.11 & 17.31 & 17.08 & 16.42 & 16.31 & 15.80 & 15.04 & 15.28 & 13.57 & -2.80 \\
          & (2.02) & (2.26) & (2.39) & (2.53) & (2.65) & (2.86) & (3.11) & (3.4) & (3.91) & (4.89) & (3.67) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{FFF} & 15.21 & 15.00 & 15.07 & 15.31 & 16.13 & 16.80 & 16.94 & 17.18 & 15.52 & 17.22 & 2.01 \\
          & (2.91) & (2.9) & (2.79) & (2.83) & (2.86) & (2.9) & (2.91) & (3.03) & (3.2) & (3.34) & (1.8) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{GG1} & 13.87 & 14.20 & 17.11 & 16.58 & 17.21 & 16.77 & 17.19 & 16.27 & 15.67 & 15.48 & 1.62 \\
          & (2.77) & (2.87) & (3.14) & (3.03) & (2.97) & (2.92) & (2.96) & (2.96) & (3.06) & (3.02) & (1.82) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{HH1} & 13.00 & 13.95 & 14.05 & 15.13 & 16.04 & 16.62 & 15.99 & 18.40 & 18.64 & 18.66 & 5.67 \\
          & (2.93) & (2.88) & (3.01) & (2.94) & (2.96) & (2.95) & (2.84) & (2.87) & (2.97) & (3.31) & (2.18) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{JJ1} & 20.84 & 19.93 & 17.71 & 16.33 & 15.94 & 16.64 & 15.80 & 14.93 & 12.91 & 9.27  & -11.58 \\
          & (3.53) & (2.96) & (2.67) & (2.73) & (2.76) & (2.7) & (2.8) & (2.93) & (3.07) & (3.37) & (1.47) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{KK1} & 19.68 & 14.09 & 12.97 & 12.89 & 15.25 & 15.24 & 15.39 & 16.43 & 18.38 & 20.04 & 0.36 \\
          & (4.26) & (3.42) & (3.18) & (2.97) & (2.78) & (2.63) & (2.57) & (2.6) & (2.69) & (2.99) & (2.3) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{LL1} & 14.96 & 14.79 & 15.38 & 16.74 & 14.36 & 15.91 & 15.53 & 17.10 & 18.22 & 17.33 & 2.37 \\
          & (2.83) & (2.8) & (2.87) & (2.83) & (2.75) & (2.82) & (2.86) & (3.01) & (3.31) & (3.93) & (2.57) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{MM1} & 13.50 & 16.44 & 16.91 & 15.93 & 16.03 & 16.36 & 15.65 & 16.47 & 16.49 & 16.54 & 3.05 \\
          & (4.08) & (3.42) & (3.05) & (2.9) & (2.85) & (2.66) & (2.59) & (2.55) & (2.63) & (2.87) & (2.09) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{NN1} & 12.76 & 14.75 & 15.69 & 16.82 & 17.66 & 17.52 & 17.30 & 16.25 & 15.63 & 15.97 & 3.22 \\
          & (1.9) & (2.23) & (2.42) & (2.61) & (2.8) & (3.03) & (3.27) & (3.5) & (3.91) & (4.57) & (3.63) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{NN2} & 21.75 & 20.85 & 18.57 & 17.38 & 16.17 & 15.61 & 15.25 & 14.07 & 12.42 & 8.27  & -13.48 \\
          & (3.92) & (3.1) & (2.78) & (2.59) & (2.55) & (2.58) & (2.66) & (2.84) & (3.09) & (3.51) & (1.78) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{NN3} & 16.87 & 16.36 & 15.38 & 16.23 & 16.44 & 16.26 & 16.45 & 15.82 & 15.03 & 15.59 & -1.28 \\
          & (3.03) & (2.95) & (2.93) & (2.78) & (2.84) & (2.82) & (2.88) & (2.93) & (3.09) & (3.39) & (1.84) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{AA1} & 31.82 & 15.84 & 15.13 & 14.18 & 15.26 & 15.29 & 14.99 & 13.49 & 12.75 & 11.61 & -20.22 \\
          & (4.12) & (3.41) & (3.18) & (3.18) & (3.14) & (3.02) & (2.95) & (2.82) & (2.62) & (2.31) & (3.48) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{AA2} & 11.72 & 14.53 & 15.40 & 16.30 & 17.44 & 17.68 & 17.80 & 16.82 & 18.10 & 14.64 & 2.93 \\
          & (2.17) & (2.47) & (2.6) & (2.72) & (2.9) & (2.94) & (3.1) & (3.31) & (3.65) & (4.18) & (3.12) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{AA3} & 18.56 & 17.65 & 17.47 & 17.71 & 18.29 & 17.29 & 16.37 & 14.30 & 13.79 & 8.87  & -9.69 \\
          & (2.97) & (2.91) & (2.94) & (2.91) & (2.9) & (2.82) & (2.83) & (2.84) & (2.96) & (3.3) & (1.35) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{BB2} & 17.02 & 18.80 & 17.61 & 17.69 & 17.54 & 16.11 & 16.01 & 15.29 & 14.32 & 9.93  & -7.09 \\
          & (3.49) & (2.99) & (2.8) & (2.73) & (2.74) & (2.71) & (2.74) & (2.84) & (2.9) & (3.38) & (1.24) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{BB3} & 13.62 & 12.57 & 14.43 & 15.58 & 16.41 & 16.52 & 16.30 & 18.00 & 18.30 & 18.59 & 4.98 \\
          & (2.68) & (2.8) & (2.98) & (3.06) & (3.01) & (3.04) & (3.03) & (3.11) & (3.14) & (3.03) & (1.99) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{BB5} & 16.01 & 15.64 & 16.15 & 15.59 & 16.24 & 16.20 & 15.67 & 15.96 & 15.81 & 17.09 & 1.08 \\
          & (3.27) & (3)   & (2.97) & (3.02) & (2.97) & (2.87) & (2.88) & (2.75) & (2.76) & (2.95) & (1.5) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{ABC} & 16.42 & 19.17 & 18.00 & 17.67 & 16.38 & 15.71 & 15.43 & 14.63 & 13.59 & 13.29 & -3.14 \\
          & (4.27) & (3.57) & (3.18) & (2.97) & (2.88) & (2.8) & (2.79) & (2.7) & (2.5) & (2.45) & (3.17) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{EDA} & 12.33 & 14.26 & 15.54 & 14.91 & 15.61 & 16.57 & 16.47 & 17.73 & 18.88 & 18.08 & 5.75 \\
          & (3.14) & (2.77) & (2.75) & (2.75) & (2.84) & (2.88) & (2.93) & (3.03) & (3.06) & (3.27) & (1.47) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{OPA} & 22.78 & 19.05 & 19.26 & 17.65 & 16.22 & 16.31 & 14.33 & 13.77 & 12.04 & 8.91  & -13.87 \\
          & (3.17) & (2.99) & (2.88) & (2.88) & (2.91) & (2.91) & (2.96) & (2.97) & (3.01) & (3.3) & (2.14) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{RPS} & 26.62 & 15.27 & 14.08 & 13.87 & 14.10 & 14.86 & 15.47 & 15.68 & 16.34 & 13.98 & -12.64 \\
          & (4.98) & (3.75) & (3.38) & (3.1) & (2.87) & (2.69) & (2.56) & (2.45) & (2.35) & (2.19) & (4.02) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{NOW} & 17.31 & 20.14 & 17.33 & 15.92 & 16.43 & 15.57 & 16.52 & 14.69 & 13.89 & 12.52 & -4.79 \\
          & (4.44) & (3.64) & (3.06) & (2.61) & (2.67) & (2.71) & (2.71) & (2.63) & (2.69) & (2.92) & (2.61) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{TEST} & 15.60 & 18.53 & 17.41 & 17.59 & 17.17 & 16.45 & 15.28 & 15.25 & 14.02 & 13.01 & -2.60 \\
          & (3.88) & (3.26) & (3.07) & (2.97) & (2.81) & (2.79) & (2.69) & (2.67) & (2.69) & (2.95) & (1.99) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{TRE1} & 16.91 & 19.47 & 17.24 & 17.34 & 16.12 & 15.39 & 15.34 & 15.40 & 14.64 & 12.47 & -4.44 \\
          & (4.42) & (3.56) & (2.98) & (2.77) & (2.6) & (2.55) & (2.55) & (2.63) & (2.77) & (3.1) & (2.53) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{RET1} & 35.60 & 21.44 & 18.09 & 16.72 & 15.83 & 15.00 & 12.62 & 11.44 & 10.28 & 3.20  & -32.41 \\
          & (4.45) & (3.38) & (3.03) & (2.83) & (2.71) & (2.59) & (2.53) & (2.6) & (2.72) & (3.29) & (2.99) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{LKI} & 13.84 & 12.03 & 12.67 & 13.42 & 14.77 & 15.67 & 16.52 & 18.76 & 19.53 & 23.35 & 9.52 \\
          & (4.6) & (3.42) & (3.07) & (2.76) & (2.64) & (2.54) & (2.57) & (2.63) & (2.83) & (3.51) & (3.48) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{RKI} & 13.14 & 11.54 & 13.56 & 15.33 & 15.41 & 16.14 & 16.82 & 17.85 & 19.58 & 21.11 & 7.98 \\
          & (4.06) & (3.2) & (2.89) & (2.76) & (2.63) & (2.61) & (2.62) & (2.72) & (2.97) & (3.49) & (2.44) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{TJL} & 22.17 & 19.17 & 17.97 & 15.83 & 16.07 & 15.34 & 15.12 & 13.88 & 13.67 & 11.31 & -10.87 \\
          & (4.3) & (3.4) & (3.01) & (2.75) & (2.64) & (2.53) & (2.55) & (2.64) & (2.87) & (3.46) & (2.83) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{S1P} & 9.25  & 11.46 & 12.80 & 14.61 & 16.01 & 16.45 & 18.26 & 19.03 & 19.91 & 22.72 & 13.47 \\
          & (3.34) & (2.85) & (2.73) & (2.73) & (2.77) & (2.84) & (2.97) & (2.99) & (3.22) & (3.47) & (2.4) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{YOI} & 9.22  & 11.36 & 11.89 & 13.47 & 15.49 & 16.33 & 16.78 & 19.85 & 21.52 & 24.58 & 15.36 \\
          & (2.94) & (2.71) & (2.65) & (2.74) & (2.81) & (2.9) & (3.02) & (3.13) & (3.31) & (3.63) & (2.45) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{IYA} & 13.61 & 15.24 & 15.31 & 16.06 & 15.82 & 16.30 & 15.95 & 14.56 & 16.06 & 21.42 & 7.82 \\
          & (2.5) & (2.55) & (2.62) & (2.76) & (2.9) & (3.07) & (3.16) & (3.29) & (3.51) & (4.04) & (2.97) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{TDK} & 6.78  & 9.29  & 11.12 & 12.11 & 13.25 & 16.20 & 17.86 & 20.25 & 23.53 & 30.18 & 23.40 \\
          & (2.92) & (2.88) & (2.82) & (2.81) & (2.81) & (2.88) & (2.93) & (3.02) & (3.14) & (3.31) & (1.79) \\
\end{adjustbox}
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{longtable}%
```

Comment: Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.How to make a table fit onto a page, apart from other factors, depends on font and margin sizes.

Comment: On a fundamental level, longtable and adjustbox or incompatible.  First adjustbox only works on boxes, and boxes cannot split over two pages.

Comment: thank you all. I will keep all these info in mind, I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no document class given in the example code in the question, I just guessed one. Depending on the actual document class, you font size and/or the value of `\tabcolsep` should be adjusted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},
         input-decimal-markers={.}, 
         group-separator={,}, 
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-align-text-pre = false,
         table-align-text-post = false,}
         
\begin{document}




{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.25pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{@{}l*{10}{S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=)]}S[table-format=-2.2,table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=)]@{}}
    \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}\\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Town}} & {\textbf{Col1}} & {\textbf{Col2}} & {\textbf{Col3}} & {\textbf{Col4}} & {\textbf{Col5}} & {\textbf{Col6}} & {\textbf{Col7}} & {\textbf{Col8}} & {\textbf{Col9}} & {\textbf{Col10}} & {\textbf{Col11}} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Add caption - continued from previous page}\\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Town}} & {\textbf{Col1}} & {\textbf{Col2}} & {\textbf{Col3}} & {\textbf{Col4}} & {\textbf{Col5}} & {\textbf{Col6}} & {\textbf{Col7}} & {\textbf{Col8}} & {\textbf{Col9}} & {\textbf{Col10}} & {\textbf{Col11}} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    AAA & 8.88  & 12.34 & 13.74 & 15.17 & 16.45 & 18.03 & 18.49 & 19.09 & 19.02 & 19.21 & 10.34 \\*
          & (3.29) & (2.98) & (2.9) & (2.84) & (2.87) & (2.89) & (2.98) & (3.05) & (2.99) & (3.33) & (2.73) \\ 
    \addlinespace
    BBB & 20.84 & 18.73 & 17.47 & 15.45 & 16.33 & 15.55 & 15.17 & 14.50 & 14.00 & 12.25 & -8.59 \\*
          & (3.82) & (3.5) & (3.27) & (3.13) & (3)   & (2.89) & (2.81) & (2.81) & (2.68) & (2.42) & (3.06) \\
     \addlinespace
    CCC & 14.64 & 14.40 & 15.83 & 16.36 & 17.31 & 17.13 & 16.88 & 16.57 & 15.44 & 15.86 & 1.23 \\*
          & (2.71) & (2.96) & (2.92) & (2.89) & (2.92) & (2.99) & (2.9) & (2.99) & (3.14) & (3.11) & (1.77) \\
    \addlinespace
    DDD & 8.60  & 12.13 & 13.07 & 14.58 & 15.95 & 16.57 & 17.34 & 18.66 & 20.21 & 23.41 & 14.82 \\*
          & (3.31) & (3.08) & (2.91) & (2.86) & (2.81) & (2.79) & (2.84) & (2.84) & (2.99) & (3.42) & (2.28) \\
    \addlinespace
    EEE & 16.36 & 17.11 & 17.31 & 17.08 & 16.42 & 16.31 & 15.80 & 15.04 & 15.28 & 13.57 & -2.80 \\*
          & (2.02) & (2.26) & (2.39) & (2.53) & (2.65) & (2.86) & (3.11) & (3.4) & (3.91) & (4.89) & (3.67) \\
    \addlinespace
    FFF & 15.21 & 15.00 & 15.07 & 15.31 & 16.13 & 16.80 & 16.94 & 17.18 & 15.52 & 17.22 & 2.01 \\*
          & (2.91) & (2.9) & (2.79) & (2.83) & (2.86) & (2.9) & (2.91) & (3.03) & (3.2) & (3.34) & (1.8) \\
    \addlinespace
    GG1 & 13.87 & 14.20 & 17.11 & 16.58 & 17.21 & 16.77 & 17.19 & 16.27 & 15.67 & 15.48 & 1.62 \\*
          & (2.77) & (2.87) & (3.14) & (3.03) & (2.97) & (2.92) & (2.96) & (2.96) & (3.06) & (3.02) & (1.82) \\
    \addlinespace
    HH1 & 13.00 & 13.95 & 14.05 & 15.13 & 16.04 & 16.62 & 15.99 & 18.40 & 18.64 & 18.66 & 5.67 \\*
          & (2.93) & (2.88) & (3.01) & (2.94) & (2.96) & (2.95) & (2.84) & (2.87) & (2.97) & (3.31) & (2.18) \\
    \addlinespace
    JJ1 & 20.84 & 19.93 & 17.71 & 16.33 & 15.94 & 16.64 & 15.80 & 14.93 & 12.91 & 9.27  & -11.58 \\*
          & (3.53) & (2.96) & (2.67) & (2.73) & (2.76) & (2.7) & (2.8) & (2.93) & (3.07) & (3.37) & (1.47) \\
    \addlinespace
    KK1 & 19.68 & 14.09 & 12.97 & 12.89 & 15.25 & 15.24 & 15.39 & 16.43 & 18.38 & 20.04 & 0.36 \\*
          & (4.26) & (3.42) & (3.18) & (2.97) & (2.78) & (2.63) & (2.57) & (2.6) & (2.69) & (2.99) & (2.3) \\
    \addlinespace
    LL1 & 14.96 & 14.79 & 15.38 & 16.74 & 14.36 & 15.91 & 15.53 & 17.10 & 18.22 & 17.33 & 2.37 \\*
          & (2.83) & (2.8) & (2.87) & (2.83) & (2.75) & (2.82) & (2.86) & (3.01) & (3.31) & (3.93) & (2.57) \\
    \addlinespace
    MM1 & 13.50 & 16.44 & 16.91 & 15.93 & 16.03 & 16.36 & 15.65 & 16.47 & 16.49 & 16.54 & 3.05 \\*
          & (4.08) & (3.42) & (3.05) & (2.9) & (2.85) & (2.66) & (2.59) & (2.55) & (2.63) & (2.87) & (2.09) \\
    \addlinespace
    NN1 & 12.76 & 14.75 & 15.69 & 16.82 & 17.66 & 17.52 & 17.30 & 16.25 & 15.63 & 15.97 & 3.22 \\*
          & (1.9) & (2.23) & (2.42) & (2.61) & (2.8) & (3.03) & (3.27) & (3.5) & (3.91) & (4.57) & (3.63) \\
    \addlinespace
    NN2 & 21.75 & 20.85 & 18.57 & 17.38 & 16.17 & 15.61 & 15.25 & 14.07 & 12.42 & 8.27  & -13.48 \\*
          & (3.92) & (3.1) & (2.78) & (2.59) & (2.55) & (2.58) & (2.66) & (2.84) & (3.09) & (3.51) & (1.78) \\
    \addlinespace
    NN3 & 16.87 & 16.36 & 15.38 & 16.23 & 16.44 & 16.26 & 16.45 & 15.82 & 15.03 & 15.59 & -1.28 \\*
          & (3.03) & (2.95) & (2.93) & (2.78) & (2.84) & (2.82) & (2.88) & (2.93) & (3.09) & (3.39) & (1.84) \\
    \addlinespace
    AA1 & 31.82 & 15.84 & 15.13 & 14.18 & 15.26 & 15.29 & 14.99 & 13.49 & 12.75 & 11.61 & -20.22 \\*
          & (4.12) & (3.41) & (3.18) & (3.18) & (3.14) & (3.02) & (2.95) & (2.82) & (2.62) & (2.31) & (3.48) \\
    \addlinespace
    AA2 & 11.72 & 14.53 & 15.40 & 16.30 & 17.44 & 17.68 & 17.80 & 16.82 & 18.10 & 14.64 & 2.93 \\*
          & (2.17) & (2.47) & (2.6) & (2.72) & (2.9) & (2.94) & (3.1) & (3.31) & (3.65) & (4.18) & (3.12) \\
    \addlinespace
    AA3 & 18.56 & 17.65 & 17.47 & 17.71 & 18.29 & 17.29 & 16.37 & 14.30 & 13.79 & 8.87  & -9.69 \\*
          & (2.97) & (2.91) & (2.94) & (2.91) & (2.9) & (2.82) & (2.83) & (2.84) & (2.96) & (3.3) & (1.35) \\
    \addlinespace
    BB2 & 17.02 & 18.80 & 17.61 & 17.69 & 17.54 & 16.11 & 16.01 & 15.29 & 14.32 & 9.93  & -7.09 \\*
          & (3.49) & (2.99) & (2.8) & (2.73) & (2.74) & (2.71) & (2.74) & (2.84) & (2.9) & (3.38) & (1.24) \\
    \addlinespace
    BB3 & 13.62 & 12.57 & 14.43 & 15.58 & 16.41 & 16.52 & 16.30 & 18.00 & 18.30 & 18.59 & 4.98 \\*
          & (2.68) & (2.8) & (2.98) & (3.06) & (3.01) & (3.04) & (3.03) & (3.11) & (3.14) & (3.03) & (1.99) \\
    \addlinespace
    BB5 & 16.01 & 15.64 & 16.15 & 15.59 & 16.24 & 16.20 & 15.67 & 15.96 & 15.81 & 17.09 & 1.08 \\*
          & (3.27) & (3)   & (2.97) & (3.02) & (2.97) & (2.87) & (2.88) & (2.75) & (2.76) & (2.95) & (1.5) \\
    \addlinespace
    ABC & 16.42 & 19.17 & 18.00 & 17.67 & 16.38 & 15.71 & 15.43 & 14.63 & 13.59 & 13.29 & -3.14 \\*
          & (4.27) & (3.57) & (3.18) & (2.97) & (2.88) & (2.8) & (2.79) & (2.7) & (2.5) & (2.45) & (3.17) \\
    \addlinespace
    EDA & 12.33 & 14.26 & 15.54 & 14.91 & 15.61 & 16.57 & 16.47 & 17.73 & 18.88 & 18.08 & 5.75 \\*
          & (3.14) & (2.77) & (2.75) & (2.75) & (2.84) & (2.88) & (2.93) & (3.03) & (3.06) & (3.27) & (1.47) \\
    \addlinespace
    OPA & 22.78 & 19.05 & 19.26 & 17.65 & 16.22 & 16.31 & 14.33 & 13.77 & 12.04 & 8.91  & -13.87 \\*
          & (3.17) & (2.99) & (2.88) & (2.88) & (2.91) & (2.91) & (2.96) & (2.97) & (3.01) & (3.3) & (2.14) \\
    \addlinespace
    RPS & 26.62 & 15.27 & 14.08 & 13.87 & 14.10 & 14.86 & 15.47 & 15.68 & 16.34 & 13.98 & -12.64 \\*
          & (4.98) & (3.75) & (3.38) & (3.1) & (2.87) & (2.69) & (2.56) & (2.45) & (2.35) & (2.19) & (4.02) \\
    \addlinespace
    NOW & 17.31 & 20.14 & 17.33 & 15.92 & 16.43 & 15.57 & 16.52 & 14.69 & 13.89 & 12.52 & -4.79 \\*
          & (4.44) & (3.64) & (3.06) & (2.61) & (2.67) & (2.71) & (2.71) & (2.63) & (2.69) & (2.92) & (2.61) \\
    \addlinespace
    TEST & 15.60 & 18.53 & 17.41 & 17.59 & 17.17 & 16.45 & 15.28 & 15.25 & 14.02 & 13.01 & -2.60 \\*
          & (3.88) & (3.26) & (3.07) & (2.97) & (2.81) & (2.79) & (2.69) & (2.67) & (2.69) & (2.95) & (1.99) \\
    \addlinespace
    TRE1 & 16.91 & 19.47 & 17.24 & 17.34 & 16.12 & 15.39 & 15.34 & 15.40 & 14.64 & 12.47 & -4.44 \\*
          & (4.42) & (3.56) & (2.98) & (2.77) & (2.6) & (2.55) & (2.55) & (2.63) & (2.77) & (3.1) & (2.53) \\
    \addlinespace
    RET1 & 35.60 & 21.44 & 18.09 & 16.72 & 15.83 & 15.00 & 12.62 & 11.44 & 10.28 & 3.20  & -32.41 \\*
          & (4.45) & (3.38) & (3.03) & (2.83) & (2.71) & (2.59) & (2.53) & (2.6) & (2.72) & (3.29) & (2.99) \\
    \addlinespace
    LKI & 13.84 & 12.03 & 12.67 & 13.42 & 14.77 & 15.67 & 16.52 & 18.76 & 19.53 & 23.35 & 9.52 \\*
          & (4.6) & (3.42) & (3.07) & (2.76) & (2.64) & (2.54) & (2.57) & (2.63) & (2.83) & (3.51) & (3.48) \\
    \addlinespace
    RKI & 13.14 & 11.54 & 13.56 & 15.33 & 15.41 & 16.14 & 16.82 & 17.85 & 19.58 & 21.11 & 7.98 \\*
          & (4.06) & (3.2) & (2.89) & (2.76) & (2.63) & (2.61) & (2.62) & (2.72) & (2.97) & (3.49) & (2.44) \\
    \addlinespace
    TJL & 22.17 & 19.17 & 17.97 & 15.83 & 16.07 & 15.34 & 15.12 & 13.88 & 13.67 & 11.31 & -10.87 \\*
          & (4.3) & (3.4) & (3.01) & (2.75) & (2.64) & (2.53) & (2.55) & (2.64) & (2.87) & (3.46) & (2.83) \\
    \addlinespace
    S1P & 9.25  & 11.46 & 12.80 & 14.61 & 16.01 & 16.45 & 18.26 & 19.03 & 19.91 & 22.72 & 13.47 \\*
          & (3.34) & (2.85) & (2.73) & (2.73) & (2.77) & (2.84) & (2.97) & (2.99) & (3.22) & (3.47) & (2.4) \\
    \addlinespace
    YOI & 9.22  & 11.36 & 11.89 & 13.47 & 15.49 & 16.33 & 16.78 & 19.85 & 21.52 & 24.58 & 15.36 \\*
          & (2.94) & (2.71) & (2.65) & (2.74) & (2.81) & (2.9) & (3.02) & (3.13) & (3.31) & (3.63) & (2.45) \\
    \addlinespace
    IYA & 13.61 & 15.24 & 15.31 & 16.06 & 15.82 & 16.30 & 15.95 & 14.56 & 16.06 & 21.42 & 7.82 \\*
          & (2.5) & (2.55) & (2.62) & (2.76) & (2.9) & (3.07) & (3.16) & (3.29) & (3.51) & (4.04) & (2.97) \\
    \addlinespace
    TDK & 6.78  & 9.29  & 11.12 & 12.11 & 13.25 & 16.20 & 17.86 & 20.25 & 23.53 & 30.18 & 23.40 \\*
          & (2.92) & (2.88) & (2.82) & (2.81) & (2.81) & (2.88) & (2.93) & (3.02) & (3.14) & (3.31) & (1.79) \\
\end{longtable}%
 }
\end{document}
```